# Regular expression to find and replace

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio

I am looking for a regualr expression to find in VS2010 solution files for string.empty and replace with string.IsNullOrEmpty

for ex `if (strText != string.Empty)` to `string.IsNullOrEmpty(strText)`

Comment: Before replacing your check in the source code , you may take a look at [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS2012 this has become a lot easier, since the Regex language used was improved quite a bit:

Search:

```
 \b(?<variable>[\w_-]+)\s*==\s*string.Empty
```

Replace:

```
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(${variable})
```

The overall idea is the same for Visual Studio 2010:

Search:

```
 {[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+}:b*==:b*string\.Empty
```

Replace:

```
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(\1)
```

And as others have noted, be sure to have either unit tests to verify you didn't break anything, or check each replacement to be sure.